# Have vs. Has in third person of unknown gender?

Tags: verbs

Let's take the sentence "Have they entered their password?", where we use "they" meaning "he/she", a third person of any or unknown gender. If we replace the pronoun "they" with a more specific noun, e.g. "the user" we'll also need to replace "Have" with "Has" — "Has the user entered the password?".

For some reason I'm thinking that there's a rule in English that say that pronouns can replace nouns without changing the structure of the sentence. Since using "they" as "he/she" is relatively new, does this mean that that old rule is no longer universal? Or is the sentence "Has they entered the password?" now grammatically correct?

Comment: Using *they* as a singular, gender-neutral third-person pronoun still uses plural syntax. Despite describing *one person*, it is still written as ***have*** *they*.

Comment: There's never been a rule in American English that pronouns replace nouns without changing the tense of the verb. *My whole family is coming to Seattle for a reunion.  They are staying ...* And when *you* was substituted for *thou*, we didn't keep the 2nd person singular conjugation.

Comment: No, using *they* in this way is extremely old. It's not new at all.

Comment: Let's take the sentence "Have you entered your password?", where we use "you" meaning a person of unknown gender. If we replace the pronoun "you" with a more specific noun, e.g. "the user" we'll also need to replace "have" with "has" — "Has the user entered the password?" Does this mean that the sentence "Has you entered the password?" is now grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to the OED "they" can be a singular or plural third person pronoun. When used with a verb it usually takes the third person plural form. "They are" as opposed to "they is", "they run" as opposed to "they runs". If there is such a rule about pronouns, then "they" is an exception no matter what they <strike>says</strike> say.

Comment: Upvote for the cross-out.

Comment: Is you sure it works that way? :)